# Redirect subfolder to rooot htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, root, http-status-code-301, subdirectory

I've a Joomla website installed in domainame.tld/subfolder
I'll physically move it to the root of the domain name and I would like to create a redirect that simply redirects all traffic from the subfolder to the root. Example:

domain.tld/eshop/category/product to redirect to domain.td/category/product

Thank you !

Best Regards,

Teodor Ovcharov

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^eshop/(.*) http://domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^directoryname(.*) http://domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]

This is the right code to use !!!